# ¿Como incrementar el tamaño de envio en net core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy realizando una aplicacion en net core la cual requiero subir multiples imagenes, a la hora de subir y revasar lo permitido que dan (30mb) me sale el siguiente error: `Failed to read the request form. Request body too large. The max request body size is 30000000 bytes.`
estuve intentando las formas de poder arreglarlo como se muestra en la siguiente pregunta [Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

La primera forma que hice fue en mi archivo Program.cs realice lo siguente y no me funciono:

```
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
 options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
 options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
 options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

La segunda que realice fue en mi controlador colocar la siguiente instrucción `[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600)]`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CrearEvento(Evento evento)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Pero tampoco tuve éxito, alguien me podria decir si estoy haciendo algo mal? o si me falto algo por colocar? se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Ya revisaste este [enlace](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20369)?, dice que hay que revisar el IIS también

Comment: Lo leí hace rato pero aqui mi duda es que en mi proyecto no estoy utilizando para nada un web.config, es entonces necesario crearlo para este tipo de situación?

Comment: Segun yo, no obligatoriamente, checa este otro [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005408/c-unable-to-write-data-to-the-transport-connection-broken-pipe-when-using-res), agregaron mas información a la petición

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿Estás probando desde localhost? ¿Estás probando desde un web server?

Comment: Estoy haciendo puebas por local, para posterior irme a un host, es por eso que pregunto si es forzoso en el IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a @MrDonPh0x por su respuesta pude resolverlo, lo realice de la siguente manera:
En mi controlador coloco las siguientes instrucciones:

```
[HttpPost]
    [RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue)]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CrearEvento(Evento evento)
    {
```

Espero les pueada ayudar.